# How can I draw arrow like directory tree format in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, trees

I want to draw following figure, I was not able to manage drawing its arrow format where like a tree-like format:

[image]

Reference: [The Linux Programming Interface, Figure 41-1](https://man7.org/tlpi/)

---

My beginner approach:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        arrow/.style={->, >=stealth, semithick},
    ] %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,4);
    [
    >=latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,shape aspect=1,
    % arrow/.style={->, >=stealth, very thick},
    % arrow/.style={<->, >=stealth, semithick},
    block/.style={}
    every node/.style = {font=\footnotesize}
    ]
    \node[
        rectangle,
        double=black,
        double distance =0.5pt,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        shape aspect=0.2,
        font={\scriptsize\baselineskip=8pt},
        inner xsep=3pt,
        align=left,
    ]  (A) at (1,4) {\scriptsize \$ gcc -g -c \\ \,\, -fPIC - Wall \\ \,\, mod1.c mod2.c mod3.c};

    \node[circle,
        shape border rotate=90,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        draw] (B) at (-0.9,4.3) {\tiny 1};

    \node[
        rectangle,
        double=black,
        double distance =0.5pt,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        font={\scriptsize\baselineskip=8pt},
        inner xsep=3pt,
        align=left,
    ]  (B) at (2,2) {mod1.o code};

    \node[
        rectangle,
        double=black,
        double distance =0.5pt,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        font={\scriptsize\baselineskip=8pt},
        inner xsep=3pt,
        align=left,
    ]  (C) at (2,1) {mod2.o code};


    \node[
        rectangle,
        double=black,
        double distance =0.5pt,
        shape border rotate=90,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        font={\scriptsize\baselineskip=8pt},
        inner xsep=3pt,
        align=left,
    ]  (D) at (2,0) {mod3.o code};

    \draw [arrow] (A.south) -- (B.west);
    \draw [arrow] (A.south) -- (C.west);
    \draw [arrow] (A.south) -- (D.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I was unable to manage to draw tree-format arrows as:

```bash
[*]
 │   
 ├──> [...]
 ├──> [...]
 └──> [...]
```

Comment: Tikz provides several ways to do it. Search e.g. for |– or graphs in the pgfmanual.

Comment: Ah I was working on pgfmanul version 1.18, that's why I was not able to find a way to do it.

Comment: Fine. Looks like you can move many common options to a small number of format statements. Best examples, when the manual explains statement \tikz[]{}

Comment: sorry I did not get the` common options to a small number of format statements.` => you mean the node format definitions right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for having been too brief. Ah, see the answer from Zarko.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

In MWE below nodes are positioned relatively to each other. Also are defined styles for nodes and by this made picture code significantly shorter. For arrow are used orthogonal coordinates `|-` (for details of its use see TikZ & PGF manual, section 13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines) as suggested in @ MS-SPO comment:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                 positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
     C/.style = {circle, draw, font=\footnotesize},
     N/.style = {draw, very thick,
                 font=\small, align=left,
                 inner sep=5pt}
                        ]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);
%
\node (n1) [N] at (3,4) {\$ gcc -g -c \\ 
                         \hphantom{\$ } -fPIC - Wall \\
                         \hphantom{\$ } mod1.c mod2.c mod3.c};
    \node[C, below left = 0 and 2mm of n1.north west] {1};
\node (n2) [N, below right=of n1.south]     {mod1.o code};
\node (n3) [N, below=of n2]     {mod2.o code};
\node (n4) [N, below=of n3]     {mod3.o code};
%
\draw[arr] (n1) |- (n2);
\draw[arr] (n1 |- n2) |- (n3);
\draw[arr] (n1 |- n3) |- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comment, you only need to change style of `C` nodes (to some extend only). For example:

```
...
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
     C/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=1pt}, % <--- text in node will be \normalsize
     N/.style = {draw, very thick,
                 font=\small, align=left,
                 inner sep=5pt}
                        ]
...
```

gives

[image]

At bigger font in circle will enlarge circle too.

Comment: Thanks its golden. Is it possible to keep `1` larger font while keeping the circle size same? I play around but when I try to increase the font size circle also becomes larger

Comment: @alper, yes, it is possible to some extend. You only need to change `C/.style` accordingly. For example to `C/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=1pt},`. See ddendum to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, in double column is it possible to start grid from most left side of the column? looks like it starts 4 space inside by default

Comment: @alper, yes this is possible too. Change node distance to `node distance = 4mm and 10mm,`.  However, I would not use help lines. To my opinion they distract image.  If you like to have image elements on grid, nodes size will not to be consistent anymore. But this is up to you,

Comment: I was thinking to use `help lines` during drawing (to locate (x,y) position of the nodes )and make it `fill=white` when I complete it.  Instead `help lines` what can I use?

Comment: @alper, ok. Apparently you move nodes positions according to help' lines. But, what you will do when nodes sizes are not aligned with help lines steps? Distance between nodes are determined by `node distance=<vertical> and <horizontal>` so you only need to determine size of gaps between nodes as is done in answer. Only "problem" (not really) is determine where star second node) offset form south anchor of the first node. A little experiences here is more helpful than help lines. BTW, on the end you can simple removes help lines by comment it by `%` at beginning of its code line.

Comment: When I remove help-lines , all the nodes become little bit larger , is it possible to keep the figure as same size when help-lines is used? I think there was a scale option but I was not able to find it. // Thanks for the your  advices

Comment: @alper, no. >our observation is false.

Comment: For my previous question in the comment I meant there is an indent (4 space) added when I try to draw your figure inside a twocolumn, would it be possible to remove that indent please see (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651180/how-can-i-draw-a-grid-without-indent-inside-twocolumn)